# filtering items with multiple filters using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue JS and trying to use multiple filters to filter multiple products.

So, I have an example of 6 filters, `product 1` to `product 6`. And I also have 6 products with different categories. I've coded as below, but when I try to click button filter, to filter the product, it doesn't work. I've tried various ways still not working.

Can anyone help me explain it and deal with this problem?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      categories:[
        {
          category_title: 'Product 1',
          category_name: "product-1"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 2',
          category_name: "product-2"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 3',
          category_name: "product-3"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 4',
          category_name: "product-4"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 5',
          category_name: "product-5"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 6',
          category_name: "product-6"
        },
      ],
      productItems: [
        {
          name: 'Pro1',
          category: 'product-1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro2',
          category: 'product-2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro3',
          category: 'product-3'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro4',
          category: 'product-4'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro5',
          category: 'product-5'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro6',
          category: 'product-6'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productFilter(){
      return this.productItems;
    },
    filterProduct(){
      return this.productItems.filter((product) => product.category == this.categories.category_name)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.product-items span{
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="app">
  <div class="product-filter">
    <button @click="filterProduct" v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id">
      {{ cat.category_title }}
    </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-items">
    <span v-for="product in productFilter" :key="product.id">{{ product.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `filterProduct` from the computed properties to `methods`. Generally actions are to be placed inside `methods` and the `computed` properties holds the data which changes with respect to the dependent values used inside the defenition of that particular computed property.

Here I have created a data property called `activeCategory` which is being set when the user clicks any one of the category button. The `productFilter` computed property makes use of `activeCategory` data property. So when ever the data property `activeCategory` gets updated from the function `filterProduct`, the `productFilter` computed property automatically retrns new set of products.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          category_title: 'Product 1',
          category_name: "product-1"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 2',
          category_name: "product-2"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 3',
          category_name: "product-3"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 4',
          category_name: "product-4"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 5',
          category_name: "product-5"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 6',
          category_name: "product-6"
        },
      ],
      productItems: [
        {
          name: 'Pro1',
          category: 'product-1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro2',
          category: 'product-2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro3',
          category: 'product-3'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro4',
          category: 'product-4'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro5',
          category: 'product-5'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro6',
          category: 'product-6'
        },
      ],
      activeCategory: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterProduct(category) {
      this.activeCategory = category;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productFilter() {
      return this.activeCategory ?
        this.productItems.filter((product) => product.category == this.activeCategory.category_name) :
        this.productItems;
    },
  }
})
```

```css
.product-items span {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
  integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="app">
  <div class="product-filter">
    <button @click="filterProduct(cat)" v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id">
      {{ cat.category_title }}
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="product-items">
    <span v-for="product in productFilter" :key="product.id">{{ product.name }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah thank you, i got it. Thank you so much for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

The method `filterProduct` should be defined inside `methods` option and add `filtered` property that will take the filtered products when you click the button, this click button runs the method that takes the current category as parameter :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      categories: [{
          category_title: 'Product 1',
          category_name: "product-1"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 2',
          category_name: "product-2"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 3',
          category_name: "product-3"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 4',
          category_name: "product-4"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 5',
          category_name: "product-5"
        },
        {
          category_title: 'Product 6',
          category_name: "product-6"
        },
      ],
      productItems: [{
          name: 'Pro1',
          category: 'product-1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro2',
          category: 'product-2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro3',
          category: 'product-3'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro4',
          category: 'product-4'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro5',
          category: 'product-5'
        },
        {
          name: 'Pro6',
          category: 'product-6'
        },
      ],
      filtered: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productFilter() {
      return this.productItems;
    },

  },
  methods: {
    filterProduct(cat) {
      this.filtered = this.productItems.filter((product) => product.category == cat.category_name)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.product-items span {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div id="app">
  <div class="product-filter">
    <button @click="filterProduct(cat)" v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id">
      {{ cat.category_title }}
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="product-items">
    <span v-for="product in filtered" :key="product.id">{{ product.name }}</span>
  </div>
  <pre>

<pre>
{{filtered}}
</pre>
</div>
```